# How to measure the consistence of a sequence?

Tags: math, statistics, sequence

*Disclaimer: I'm very outsider in Maths.. so maybe what I'm asking is very basic. Or maybe I need help to reformulate the question.*

I would like to measure numerically the *consistency* of several sequences so I can compare and order them base on this *consistency* number.

These are some possible examples os sequences sorted (based on my opinion) from less consistent to more consistent, the examples are using a binary values, but it also can be any number of options:

- 10101
- 1010
- 101
- 10
- 0 (*)
- 1 (*)
- 110
- 11
- 111
- 1111

(*) equal consistency

There are other scenarios I don't really know how to sort them, check the following pairs, I don't really know which would be defined as more consistent:

#### Pair 1:

- 111111111111101
- 11

#### Pair 2:

- 110
- 1100

#### Pair 3:

- 1010101010
- 1111100000

I'm asking for any kind of insight about how I should proceed to calculate this measurement: formules, links to docs, suggestions, anything is welcome.

Comment: Two concepts that may be useful to you would be the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient and the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient.  Both are designed to measure the "out-of-order-ness" of a sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could count the number of "changes" (from 0 to 1 or viceversa) and divide it by the total number of elements in the sequence.

If the sequences can have things different from 1s and 0s, I would make the "distance" between each element count. So a change from 0 and 1 "costs" 1, but a change from 0 to 2 "costs" 2, etc.

```
def get_consistency(sequence)
  change = 0
  count = 0
  previous = nil
  sequence.each do |element|
    if previous then
      # define distance as whatever you want. For numbers, its abs(element-previous)
      change += distance(element, previous)
      count += 1
    end
    previous = element
  end
  count == 0 ? 0 : change / count
end
```

Comment: Looks nice.. I kind of like the version 3 of this experiment: http://labs.codecademy.com/C6Rh/1#:workspace what do you think?

Comment: I see that you didn't include my example for the distance, using the abs of the difference. I've included it here (step 4): http://labs.codecademy.com/C6Rh/2#:workspace . Also, I realized that "count" was "counting one more element that in should" (it should count the transitions, not the elements). I've fixed that in codeacadamy and my answer

Comment: I saw your example of the distance, but I wanted to play with _categorical variables_ this is because they are equal or they are not, doesn't matter the real value. I like the previous version of the `count` because if not the sequences `1,2` and `1,2,3,4` have the same value.. same for the sequences `1,1` and `1,1,1,1`.. and (IMHO) they shouldn't. The _VERSION 4_ of your example is not confusing for me because the most consistent versions have less value and there is not difference between `1` and `1,1,1`.

Comment: Check the VERSION 5 http://labs.codecademy.com/C6Rh/3#:workspace If you allow me I would like to modify your code with that version.

Comment: I think I prefer it when consistency is 0 for "perfectly constant" sequences and then it goes up as change happens. I don't like having negative values, there; they will make sorting more difficult. Can't you use two numbers to sort? Sort first by consistency, and then sort sequences with same consistency by length.

Comment: Or you could multiply consistency by some very high number, like 1000000, and then add the length, and treat that like the consistency

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63178/discussion-between-fguillen-and-kikito).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the @kikito implementation but with another flavor:

```rb
def get_consistency(sequence)
  proximity =
    sequence.each_with_index.map do |element, index|
      index > 0 ? distance(element, sequence[index-1]) : 0
    end.reduce(:-)

  proximity / sequence.length.to_f
end

def distance(value1, value2)
  value1 == value2 ? -1 : 1 # Categorical variable
end
```

Results:

```
0.7500 <- 1,1,1,1
0.4000 <- 1,1,1,1,2
0.5714 <- 1,1,1,1,2,2,2
0.2857 <- 1,1,1,1,2,2,3
0.0000 <- 1
0.0000 <- 2
-0.5000 <- 1,2
-0.7500 <- 1,2,3,4
-0.2500 <- 1,2,2,3
0.9000 <- 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
0.9900 <- 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
0.9703 <- 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
-0.9000 <- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
-0.9000 <- 1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0
0.7000 <- 1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
0.2500 <- 1,1,0,0
```

Comment: I'm using my answer but the original credits of my algorithm are for the @kikito's answer.