# How to quantify the consistency of a sequence of predictions, incl. prediction confidence, using standard function from sklearn or a similar library

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, classification

Let's say I let a classification model classify a single object multiple times but under varying circumstances. Ideally it should predict the same class again and again. But in reality its class predictions may vary.

So given a sequence of class predictions for the single object, I'd like to measure how consistent the sequence is. To be clear, this is not about comparing predictions against some ground truth. This is about consistency within the prediction sequence itself.

- For instance, a perfectly consistent prediction sequence like `class_a, class_a, class_a, class_a` should get a perfect score.
- A less consistent sequence like `class_a, class_b, class_a, class_c`
  should get a lower score.
- And a completely inconsistent sequence like
  `class_a, class_b, class_c, class_d` should get the lowest score
  possible.

The goal is to find out on what objects we may need to keep training the classification model. If the classification model is not very consistent in its predictions for a certain object, then we might need to add that object to a dataset for further training.

Preferably it works for any number of possible classes and also takes into account prediction confidences. The sequence `class_a (0.9), class_b (0.9), class_a (0.9), class_c (0.9)` should give a lower score then `class_a (0.9), class_b (0.2), class_a (0.8), class_c (0.3)`, as it's no good when the predictions are inconsistent with high confidences.

I could build something myself, but I'd like to know if there's a standard sklearn or scipy (or similar) function for this? Thanks in advance!

The comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406708/how-to-measure-the-consistence-of-a-sequence) suggests [Spearman's correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) or the [Kandell correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient). I'll look into that as well.

Comment: It may help us if you could provide some code so we can offer sklearn alternatives (if they exist). Struggling to understand what you're wanting to do.

Comment: Sorry, don't have any code yet. So far I'm just investigating standard ways of measuring consistency in predictions. But I'll try to explain a bit better what I want.

Comment: Please note that machine learning questions about methodology (selecting and designing metrics in this case) are off-topic in Stack Overflow, what you are asking is not a programming problem.

Comment: Ok after @DataSciRookie has reposted his answer I'll get rid of this one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's what you are looking for :

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

def consistency_score(predictions, confidences):
    """
    Calculate a consistency score for a sequence of predictions.
    

    """
    # Calculate base consistency as the frequency of the most common class
    most_common_class, most_common_freq = Counter(predictions).most_common(1)[0]
    base_consistency = most_common_freq / len(predictions)
    
    # Adjust consistency based on confidences
    # Penalize deviations from the most common class, especially with high confidence
    penalty = sum(conf for pred, conf in zip(predictions, confidences) if pred != most_common_class) / len(predictions)
    adjusted_consistency = max(0, base_consistency - penalty)
    
    return adjusted_consistency
```

- Example :

  ```
    predictions = ["class_a", "class_b", "class_a", "class_c"]
    confidences = [0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9]
    score_high_confidence = consistency_score(predictions, confidences)

    predictions_low_confidence = ["class_a", "class_b", "class_a", "class_c"]
    confidences_low_confidence = [0.9, 0.2, 0.8, 0.3]
    score_low_confidence = consistency_score(predictions_low_confidence, confidences_low_confidence)

    print(f"High confidence inconsistencies score: {score_high_confidence}")
    print(f"Lower confidence inconsistencies score: {score_low_confidence}")
  ```

Comment: Ha thanks, yes at least it's a very good start. And even with nicely readable coding style. :) Still I hope there's some standard way of doing this.

Comment: Hi could you please repost your answer in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/643646/standard-function-to-quantify-consistency-of-a-sequence-of-predictions). Then I can remove this question because apparently it's not in the right place.